# What is propagated? The field or its vibration?

Tags: field-theory

It is common to read or hear that "the electromagnetic field propagates at speed c". But is this accurate? Isn't its vibration what propagates at speed c?

Comment: You are going to have to be much more clear about what you mean by "vibration" and what you have in mind when you say the vibration propagates and how this is different than the field propagating.  Also, what are you considering the field? Something more physical or just a mathematical mapping of a bunch of points in space (which is technically there all the time even if it's zero).

Comment: There is a steady electric current in a conductor, this generates an electric field and a magnetic field of constant values at a certain point, that is, there is an electromagnetic field that does not change over time. Then there is a current whose charges accelerate, there is also an electromagnetic field but its value at a point changes with time, this can be seen as a propagation of a change through space, a vibration. This topic is confusing for me.